# subsetting a Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I am transitioning from R to Python. I just began using Pandas. I have an R code that subsets nicely:

```
k1 <- subset(data, Product = p.id & Month < mn & Year == yr, select = c(Time, Product))
```

Now, I want to do similar stuff in Python. this is what I have got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("../data/monthly_prod_sales.csv")


#first, index the dataset by Product. And, get all that matches a given 'p.id' and time.
 data.set_index('Product')
 k = data.ix[[p.id, 'Time']]

# then, index this subset with Time and do more subsetting..
```

I am beginning to feel that I am doing this the wrong way. perhaps, there is an elegant solution. Can anyone help? I need to extract month and year from the timestamp I have and do subsetting. Perhaps there is a one-liner that will accomplish all this:

```
k1 <- subset(data, Product = p.id & Time >= start_time & Time < end_time, select = c(Time, Product))
```

thanks.

Comment: `df.query` and `pd.eval` seem like good fits for this use case. For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I'll assume that `Time` and `Product` are columns in a `DataFrame`,  `df` is an instance of `DataFrame`, and that other variables are scalar values:

For now, you'll have to reference the `DataFrame` instance:

```
k1 = df.loc[(df.Product == p_id) & (df.Time >= start_time) & (df.Time < end_time), ['Time', 'Product']]
```

The parentheses are also necessary, because of the precedence of the `&` operator vs. the comparison operators. The `&` operator is actually an overloaded bitwise operator which has the same precedence as arithmetic operators which in turn have a higher precedence than comparison operators.

In `pandas` 0.13 a new experimental [`DataFrame.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method will be available. It's extremely similar to subset modulo the `select` argument:

With `query()` you'd do it like this:

```
df[['Time', 'Product']].query('Product == p_id and Month < mn and Year == yr')
```

Here's a simple example:

```
In [9]: df = DataFrame({'gender': np.random.choice(['m', 'f'], size=10), 'price': poisson(100, size=10)})

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
  gender  price
0      m     89
1      f    123
2      f    100
3      m    104
4      m     98
5      m    103
6      f    100
7      f    109
8      f     95
9      m     87

In [11]: df.query('gender == "m" and price < 100')
Out[11]:
  gender  price
0      m     89
4      m     98
9      m     87
```

The final query that you're interested will even be able to take advantage of chained comparisons, like this:

```
k1 = df[['Time', 'Product']].query('Product == p_id and start_time <= Time < end_time')
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. It works well. This is what I was looking for - a simple, quick solution. Many thanks again. For those searching for such solution, the time I used is like this: (data.ts >= '2012-10-01') & (data.ts < '2013-05-01') .

Comment: @Philip,   I tried your suggestion from iPython with concrete values in my conditions. They worked fine. But, when I embed the same in a program and call with parameters, I get an error - the final lines are: `code` File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 225, in wrapper       if len(self) != len(other):      Type Error: len() of unsized object

Comment: More about the above (ill-formatted) error message: I checked my data set and made sure there are no NaNs or NAs, and nothing is empty. Not sure why a call to my function errors out. I have my function like this:   `code` def get_data(data, p_id, start_time, end_time):   test_data = data.loc[(data.product == p_id) & (data.ts >= start_time) & (data.ts < end_time), ['product', 'ts']]  `code`

Comment: please ignore that error. It was error coming out of converting Python array to numpy array - and finding the mean of a column resulted in some 'dtype' error.

Answer (score 20):

Just for someone looking for a solution more similar to R:

```
df[(df.Product == p_id) & (df.Time> start_time) & (df.Time < end_time)][['Time','Product']]
```

No need for `data.loc` or `query`, but I do think it is a bit long.

Answer (score 15):

I've found that you can use any subset condition for a given column by wrapping it in []. For instance, you have a df with columns ['Product','Time', 'Year', 'Color']

And let's say you want to include products made before 2014. You could write,

```
df[df['Year'] < 2014]
```

To return all the rows where this is the case. You can add different conditions.

```
df[df['Year'] < 2014][df['Color' == 'Red']
```

Then just choose the columns you want as directed above. For instance, the product color and key for the df above,

```
df[df['Year'] < 2014][df['Color'] == 'Red'][['Product','Color']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding some points mentioned in previous answers, and to improve readability:

> No need for data.loc or query, but I do think it is a bit long.
>
> The parentheses are also necessary, because of the precedence of the & operator vs. the comparison operators.

I like to write such expressions as follows - less brackets, faster to type, easier to read. Closer to R, too.

```
q_product = df.Product == p_id
q_start = df.Time > start_time
q_end = df.Time < end_time

df.loc[q_product & q_start & q_end, c('Time,Product')]

# c is just a convenience
c = lambda v: v.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that works a bit like the subset function in R.

similar to what is asked for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868426/python-equivalent-to-subset-function-in-r)

I haven't found a way to use both the %in% = list, while using And or Or operators, but I just do those subsets one by one:

```
def subset(df, query=None, select=None, unselect=None, asindex=False, returnFullDFIfError=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Subsets a pandas DataFrame based on query conditions, and selects or unselects specified columns.

    Parameters:
    df (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame to be subsetted.
    query (str, optional): A query string to filter rows. Default is None.
    select (list, optional): Columns to be selected. Default is None.
    unselect (list, optional): Columns to be unselected. Default is None.
    asindex (bool, optional): Whether to return only the index if True. Default is False.
    returnFullDFIfError (bool, optional): Whether to return the full DataFrame if an error occurs. Default is True.

    Returns:
    pd.DataFrame or pd.Index: The subsetted DataFrame or Index, based on the given parameters.

    Examples:
    #>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4], 'C': [5, 6]})
    #>>> subset(df, query='A > 1', select=['B', 'C'])
    #>>> subset(df, query='A < 2', unselect=['C'])

    names_list = ['Alice', 'David']
    result = subset(df, query="Name %in% names_list", select=['Name', 'Age'],names_list=names_list)
    print(result)
        Name  Age
    0  Alice   25
    3  David   40

    IMPORTANT:
    You cannot combine the use of %in% and other operators like and, or, & and |.

    names_list = ['Alice', 'David']
    result = subset(df, query="Name %in% names_list or Age > 16" , select=['Name', 'Age'],names_list=names_list)
    print(result)
        Name  Age
    0  Alice   25
    3  David   40


    """
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re

    # Ensure proper types for select and unselect
    select = list(select) if select else []
    unselect = list(unselect) if unselect else []

    # Preprocess for %in% and %!in% conditions and standardize logical operators
    if query:
        df, query = _preprocess_query(df, query, kwargs)

    # Execute query
    try:
        if asindex:
            return df.query(query).index
        else:
            filtered_df = df.query(query) if query else df
            if select:
                return filtered_df[select]
            elif unselect:
                return filtered_df[[col for col in df.columns if col not in unselect]]
            else:
                return filtered_df
    except Exception as e:
        if returnFullDFIfError:
            return df
        else:
            raise e

def _preprocess_query(df, query, variables):
    """
    Preprocesses the DataFrame for %in% and %!in% conditions and standardizes logical operators.

    Parameters:
    df (pd.DataFrame): The DataFrame to be processed.
    query (str): The query string.
    variables (dict): A dictionary of variables to be used in the query.

    Returns:
    tuple: The processed DataFrame and the updated query string.
    """
    # Standardize logical operators
    query = query.replace(" or ", " | ").replace(" OR ", " | ").replace(" Or ", " | ")
    query = query.replace(" and ", " & ").replace(" AND ", " & ").replace(" And ", " & ")

    # Process %in% and %!in% conditions
    in_conditions = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*%(!?in)%\s*(\w+)', query)
    for col, operator, var in in_conditions:
        values = variables.get(var, [])
        if operator == 'in':
            df = df[df[col].isin(values)]
        else:  # operator == '!in'
            df = df[~df[col].isin(values)]

    # Remove %in% and %!in% from the query
    updated_query = re.sub(r'\w+\s*%!?in%\s*\w+', '', query)

    return df, updated_query.strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

Creating an Empty Dataframe with known Column Name:

```
Names = ['Col1','ActivityID','TransactionID']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = Names)
```

Creating a dataframe from **csv**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('...../file_name.csv')
```

Creating a dynamic filter to subset a `dtaframe`:

```
i = 12
df[df['ActivitiID'] <= i]
```

Creating a dynamic filter to subset required columns of dtaframe

```
df[df['ActivityID'] == i][['TransactionID','ActivityID']]
```