# How to filter csv data by applying conditions on certain columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am new python data analysis and having some problems to get the required data in specific format.

My data is in following format. ( please check the attached link for data in csv format as the data is quite large)

[image]

I used following commands to print the csv data in the above format

`address = 'C:\Barchatdata.csv'
 data_c = pd.read_csv(address)`

Now i want to apply if condition on Energy_Supply_per_capita >280 and then print index column, contry_area, Energy_Supply_per_capita and Avg_GDP columns.

i tried following command

`data_c.loc[data_c['Energy_Supply_per_capita'] > 280, 'Energy_Supply_per_capita']`

but got only index and Energy_Supply_per_capita columns.

How i can get the required results?

Thank you in advance.

[link to csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3T5goLL8BbXMUNxWkl4a282Q2RhZjBla1ZrLUZfRWRnZHpJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237878/subsetting-a-python-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `query`

```
cols = ['Country_Area', 'Energy_Supply_per_capita', 'Avg_GDP']
data_c.query('Energy_Supply_per_capita > 280')[cols]
```

Or equivalently with a boolean series and `loc`

```
cols = ['Country_Area', 'Energy_Supply_per_capita', 'Avg_GDP']
data_c.loc[data_c.Energy_Supply_per_capita > 280, cols]
```