# How to add another condition to filter csv data

Tags: python, pandas

My question is related to this post:

[How to filter csv data by applying conditions on certain columns in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397942/how-to-filter-csv-data-by-applying-conditions-on-certain-columns-in-python)

How would I apply another condition? For example, let's say I'm only interested in Albania and Zambia when Energy_Supply_per_capita > 280 and emissions_of_co2 < 30? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
q = "Country_Area in ['Albania','Zambia'] "+\
    "and Energy_Supply_per_capita > 280 "+\
    "and emissions_of_co2 < 30"
df.query(q)
```

Comment: One of the comments included these lines of code: cols = ['Country_Area', 'Energy_Supply_per_capita', 'Avg_GDP']
data_c.query('Energy_Supply_per_capita > 280')[cols]. How would I incorporate them? ps sorry for the poor formatting. I'm very new to stack overflow and still figuring things out.

Comment: To be more clear, how would I include the rows from another column of data, such as Avg_GDP for those countries? Thanks again

Comment: @PistolPete, it's not clear - what are you trying to achieve. Please edit your question and provide a small reproducible data set and a desired data set