# Python equivalent to subset function in r

Tags: python, r

I don't know python at all but the project I'm currently working on must be done using it, I have this r code

`y_train <- subset(train_df_cleaned_2, Id==IdExec)$Y`

and I need to do the exact same thing in python. How do I do it? Thank you

Comment: maybe this can do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578925/2673238

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this in Python is comprehension, e.g.:

```
y_train = [x for x in train_df_cleaned_2 if x.Id == IdExec]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer using this :[subsetting a Python DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237878/subsetting-a-python-dataframe)

```
y = train[(train.NflId == train.NflIdRusher)][['Yards']]
```

thanks for the help everyone