# Nested Values from a Json value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

From a json file, I know you can use json_normalize to convert said json file into a pandas Dataframe. When there are nested dictionaries, json_normalize does flatten them. However, for my json file, the nested dictionaries are within a list, see `Var2` below. How would I access the elements within Var2 and convert them to be there own dataframe?

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
data = [
        {"Id":1,"Var1":2,"Var2":[{"Var2.1":4,"Var2.2":3}],"Var3":3},
        {"Id":2,"Var1":2,"Var2":[{"Var2.1":4}],"Var3":3},
        {"Id":3,"Var1":2,"Var2":[{"Var2.1":4,"Var2.2":3,"Var2.3":2}],"Var3":3}
        ]
df = json_normalize(data)
```

I have tried `df["Var2"].apply(json_normalize)`, but that resulted in a really weird output.

How have others solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subsetting a Python DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237878/subsetting-a-python-dataframe)

Comment: No, the above does not answer my question.

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(data)
df['Var2'] = df['Var2'].apply(pd.Series)

result = df['Var2'].apply(pd.Series)
```

---

**df:**

```
Id  Var1    Var2                                    Var3
0   1   2   {'Var2.1': 4, 'Var2.2': 3}              3
1   2   2   {'Var2.1': 4}                           3 
2   3   2   {'Var2.1': 4, 'Var2.2': 3, 'Var2.3': 2} 3
```

---

**result:**

```
    Var2.1  Var2.2  Var2.3
0   4.0     3.0     NaN
1   4.0     NaN     NaN
2   4.0     3.0     2.0
```